# Determining an appropriate analysis approach

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sas

I have data (that can be seen at the end of this post) in which 13 judges scored differing amounts of posters. Judges are randomly assigned blocks of poster numbers to score. We can assume poster numbers are assigned randomly. I wish to answer three questions:

$\bullet$ What is the effect on the rankings due to having different number of judges evaluating posters?
$\bullet$ What is the effect on the rankings due to having the number of posters judged vary from judge to judge?
$\bullet$ Are there advantages or disadvantages to being evaluated by certain judges?

For each question, would it be sensical to run a Kruskal-Wallis test? I know Kruskal-Wallis requires independent and random groups so would it not be applicable because not all posters are of the same quality? If Kruskal-Wallis is not applicable to any of the three questions, what alternative test should I consider?

Would a Mixed Model ANOVA make more sense? For answering question 3, SAS gives the following output but I'm not sure how to interpret the results. I've done one and two way ANOVA's before but not mixed models. I wasn't sure if an interaction would be necessary so I didn't include that.

[image]

[image]

```
awards_wide <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
Poster J1   J2  J3  J4  J5  J6  J7  J8  J9  J10 J11 J12 J13
1   29  25  .   .   .   22  25  .   .   .   .   .   .
2   21  24  .   .   .   19  14  .   .   .   .   .   .
3   21  .   .   .   .   23  25  .   .   .   .   .   .
4   25  .   .   .   20  21  .   .   .   .   .   .   .
5   24  .   .   .   22  17  .   .   .   .   .   .   .
6   25  .   .   .   16  26  .   .   .   .   .   .   .
7   .   .   .   28  20  21  .   .   .   .   .   .   .
8   .   25  .   24  27  26  .   .   .   .   .   .   .
9   .   .   .   27  21  23  .   .   .   .   .   27  .
10  .   .   .   22  29  .   .   .   .   22  .   .   .
11  .   .   .   6   14  .   .   .   .   11  .   .   .
12  .   .   .   17  17  .   .   .   .   22  .   .   .
13  .   .   .   19  .   .   .   20  .   20  .   .   .
14  .   .   .   20  .   .   .   16  .   21  .   .   .
15  .   .   .   21  .   .   .   27  .   27  .   .   .
16  .   .   22  .   .   .   .   27  .   23  25  .   .
17  .   .   22  .   .   .   .   28  .   27  .   .   .
18  .   .   25  .   .   .   .   22  23  .   28  .   .
19  .   .   23  .   .   .   .   26  9   .   .   .   .
20  .   .   26  .   .   .   .   29  25  .   .   .   .
21  .   23  27  .   .   .   .   .   20  .   .   22  .
22  .   .   .   .   16  .   .   .   10  .   .   21  .
23  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   ns  .   .   ns  .
25  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   13  .   .   14  14
27  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   17  .   .   28  28
28  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   ns  .
29  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   13  17  20
30  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   22  16  19
31  .   .   .   .   .   .   20  .   .   .   15  .   21
32  .   .   .   .   .   .   22  .   .   .   22  .   19
33  .   .   .   .   .   .   27  .   .   .   25  .   21
34  18  .   .   .   .   .   13  .   .   .   17  .   .
35  25  .   .   .   .   .   19  .   .   .   13  .   .
')
```

The data can then be converted from wide to long format (in R statistical software) using

```
awards_wide$Poster <- factor(awards_wide$Poster)
awards_wide[,2:14] <- sapply(awards_wide[,2:14],as.character)
awards_wide[,2:14] <- sapply(awards_wide[,2:14],as.numeric)
library(tidyr)
data_long <- gather(awards_wide, judge, score, J1:J13, factor_key=F)
data_long
data_long<-na.omit(data_long)
```